# Using JAXB with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, jar, jaxb

Searched many posts out there, still not enough information regarding this.

I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:289)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1512)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$1.run(ClassLoader.java:330)
```

Question:

How do I use JAXB in GAE. I am using a third party library that makes use of JAXB

What jars should I include?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem and was able to resolve it by adding < property name="com.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize" value="true" / > to system-properties in appengine-web.xml file.